I the list of Fourier coefficients unique for every function?
I’ve recently encountered in my studies a way to express functions as vectors, in particular using the Fourier coefficients and the complex exponentials as a base. This means that
$\vec{c} \cdot \vec{e} = f(x)$
where the vector $\vec{c}$ is the list of all Fourier coefficients, and $\vec{e}$ is the base of complex exponentials, so that
$$\vec{c} \cdot \vec{e} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}$$
if we assume that an inverse of the dot product exists we can write $\vec{c}$ as
$\vec{c} = \frac{f(x)}{\vec{e}}$.
Of course the inverse of the dot product (what here is represented as a fraction) does not exists, as there are infinte vectors$\vec{a}$ that satisfy the equation $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ab$ given $\vec{b}$ and $ab$. But does this mean that infinite different vectors of Fourier coefficients exists for every function? if so, what distinguishes the "standard" coefficients?

Remember that your formal "dot product" $\vec c\cdot\vec e$ is really not a dot product at all, but rather a convenient shorthand for a linear combination. Indeed, $\vec c$ and $\vec e$ are not even elements of the same space - $\vec c$ is an infinite sequence of numbers, while $\vec e$ is an infinite sequence of functions. Your "inverse scalar product" exists. It is given by the projection onto the subspace spanned by s single basis vector and is indeed how you obtain the Fourier components in the first place. The components of a vector in terms of a basis are always unique.

Couldn’t you view c as a constant function, so that the “dot product” is the canonical inner product on $\ell^2(\mathcal C^{\infty}(\Bbb R, \Bbb R^2))$, where the norm on $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ is the supremum norm and we make the natural identification $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$?

what if i see the vector $\vec{e}$ as a vector for every t (as Divide1918 said) or I see the vector $\vec{c}$ as a vector of functions that are constant with t? also, how is the basis that you describe composed?

@Divide1918 $\vec{e}$ will not be in $\ell^2$ since the norm of each $e^{inx}$ is $1$.

True. What about $\ell^{\infty}(L^2(K))$ (square-integrable on compact subsets) though? Then $| e|=1$ and the pointwise Euclidean dot product (take the $\Bbb R^2 $ norm) is a map which sends each $x\in\Bbb R$ to (the image of) an inner product. This is integrable as a function of x on compact subsets of $\Bbb R$, and the integral is still an inner product (a.e.)
